# undefined method `each_pair' for :name:Symbol with Chartkick and jsapi.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, chartkick

I've been trying to debug this issue for 3 days now. Can't seem to figure out what would be throwing this error..any help is much appreciated..

I am trying generated a line chart using google charts and chartkick:

```
Events index.html.erb

<h1>Events</h1>


<%= line_chart @events.group(:name).count %>

<%= line_chart @events.group_by_day(:created_at).count %>

<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Data</th>
    <th>URI</th>
  </tr>
    <% @events.each do |event| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= event.name %></td>
        <td><%= event.data %></td>
        <td><%= event.uri %></td>
        <td><%= event.created_at.to_s(:long) %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>
```

This line

```
<%= line_chart @events.group(:name).count %>
```

does not work. However, when I do the following:

```
<%= line_chart @events.only(:name) %>
```

the chart populates...

My Events controller is the following:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @domain = Domain.where(id: params[:domain_id]).first
    @events = @domain.events
  end
end
```

Any clue...what might be the issue? I am currently using Rails 4 + Mongoid 4.0.0.

I can't find any resources that point to this issue.. Look forward to hearing from someone.

Here is my stack trace:

```
origin (2.1.1) lib/origin/pipeline.rb:101:in `evolve'
origin (2.1.1) lib/origin/pipeline.rb:40:in `group'
origin (2.1.1) lib/origin/aggregable.rb:44:in `block in group'
origin (2.1.1) lib/origin/aggregable.rb:112:in `block in aggregation'
origin (2.1.1) lib/origin/aggregable.rb:106:in `tap'
origin (2.1.1) lib/origin/aggregable.rb:106:in `aggregation'
origin (2.1.1) lib/origin/aggregable.rb:43:in `group'
mongoid (4.0.0) lib/mongoid/relations/referenced/many.rb:413:in `public_send'
mongoid (4.0.0) lib/mongoid/relations/referenced/many.rb:413:in `block in method_missing'
mongoid (4.0.0) lib/mongoid/scopable.rb:239:in `with_scope'
mongoid (4.0.0) lib/mongoid/relations/referenced/many.rb:412:in `method_missing'
app/views/events/index.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_events_index_html_erb___334265416112498281_2178674640'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:49:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:48:in `block in render_template'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:56:in `render_with_layout'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `render_template'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:127:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:219:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:120:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:33:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:26:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:97:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
/Users/shaunkoo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/benchmark.rb:296:in `realtime'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:423:in `_run__2814413906838894580__process_action__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:680:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__476741460211041699__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
thin (1.6.2) lib/thin/connection.rb:86:in `block in pre_process'
thin (1.6.2) lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `catch'
thin (1.6.2) lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `pre_process'
thin (1.6.2) lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
thin (1.6.2) lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
thin (1.6.2) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
thin (1.6.2) lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:16:in `run'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:84:in `start'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Please show the context of the error/stack trace.

Comment: @SergioA. Just posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using Chartkick..I switched over to Google Charts and it worked like a charm. It seems that there might be compatibility issues with Chartkick and Mongoid see post: https://github.com/ankane/chartkick/issues/83